# How can I confirm another user's sudo permissions using my sudo permissions?

Tags: sudo, sssd, freeipa

I currently manage an IDM ([FreeIPA](https://www.freeipa.org/page/Main_Page)) cluster and have full sudo rights, i.e.  I can become root via `sudo -Es`. I'd like to verify a sudo rule that I've added to FreeIPA on a specific server to confirm that the rule is being picked up properly by the host via SSSD.

How can I do this?

**NOTE:** the sudo rule is as follows:

```
$ ipa sudorule-show prod-abc-dashboard-dba
  Rule name: prod-abc-dashboard-dba
  Enabled: TRUE
  Command category: all
  User Groups: eng-data-svc
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest method I've found to accomplish this is to SSH to a server which will be picking up the sudo rule and check a user in the group that's being granted this type of access. You can use the `sudo` commands `-l` and -`U` switches:

> $ man sudo
>
> ```
> -l, --list  If no command is specified, list the allowed (and 
>             forbidden) commands for the invoking user (or the user 
>             specified by the -U option) on the current host.  A 
>             longer list format is used if this option is specified 
>             multiple times and the security policy supports a ver‐
>             bose output format.
>
> -U user, --other-user=user 
>               Used in conjunction with the -l option to list the 
>             privileges for user instead of for the invoking user.  
>             The security policy may restrict listing other users' 
>             privileges.  The sudoers policy only allows root or a 
>             user with the ALL privilege on the current host to use 
>             this option.
> ```

You can use these together like this:

```
$ sudo -lU <user>
```

#### Example

```
$ sudo -lU joeuser
Matching Defaults entries for joeuser on this host:
    requiretty, !visiblepw, always_set_home, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY HOSTNAME HISTSIZE INPUTRC KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2
    QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE", env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME
    LC_NUMERIC LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY", secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User joeuser may run the following commands on this host:
    (root) ALL
    (ALL : ALL) ALL
```

Additionally you can use multiple `-l` switches (i.e. `-ll`) to get a more verbose listing of another user's privileges, for e.g.:

```
$ sudo -llU joeuser
Matching Defaults entries for joeuser on this host:
    !visiblepw, always_set_home, match_group_by_gid, always_query_group_plugin, env_reset, env_keep="COLORS DISPLAY
    HOSTNAME HISTSIZE KDEDIR LS_COLORS", env_keep+="MAIL PS1 PS2 QTDIR USERNAME LANG LC_ADDRESS LC_CTYPE",
    env_keep+="LC_COLLATE LC_IDENTIFICATION LC_MEASUREMENT LC_MESSAGES", env_keep+="LC_MONETARY LC_NAME LC_NUMERIC
    LC_PAPER LC_TELEPHONE", env_keep+="LC_TIME LC_ALL LANGUAGE LINGUAS _XKB_CHARSET XAUTHORITY",
    secure_path=/sbin\:/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin

User joeuser may run the following commands on this host:

LDAP Role: lab-data-services-all
    RunAsUsers: root
    Commands:
        ALL

LDAP Role: ad-data_services
    RunAsUsers: root
    Commands:
        ALL

LDAP Role: ALL
    RunAsUsers: ALL
    RunAsGroups: ALL
    Commands:
        ALL
```

#### sudo version

```
$ sudo -V
Sudo version 1.8.6p3
Sudoers policy plugin version 1.8.6p3
Sudoers file grammar version 42
Sudoers I/O plugin version 1.8.6p3
```